# How do I limit the 'getColumnIndex to >= 0 Java

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on an app in Android Studio with the following code:

//added this first part to show what c is and what happens with it.  I don't use a curser that I know of and it doesn't stop my app from running fine, but I don't like having errors.

```
@Override
    public Iterator<StoredMessage> getAllArrivedMessages(
            final String clientHandle) {
        return new Iterator<StoredMessage>() {
            private Cursor c;
            private boolean hasNext;
            private final String[] selectionArgs = {
                    clientHandle,
            };


            {
                db = mqttDb.getWritableDatabase();
                // anonymous initialiser to start a suitable query
                // and position at the first row, if one exists
                if (clientHandle == null) {
                    c = db.query(ARRIVED_MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            "mtimestamp ASC");
                } else {
                    c = db.query(ARRIVED_MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME,
                            null,
                            MqttServiceConstants.CLIENT_HANDLE + "=?",
                            selectionArgs,
                            null,
                            null,
                            "mtimestamp ASC");
                }
                hasNext = c.moveToFirst();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (!hasNext){
                    c.close();
                }
                return hasNext;
            }
 @Override
            public StoredMessage next() {
                String messageId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.MESSAGE_ID));
                String clientHandle = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.CLIENT_HANDLE));
                String topic = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.DESTINATION_NAME));
                byte[] payload = c.getBlob(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.PAYLOAD));
                int qos = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.QOS));
                boolean retained = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.RETAINED)));
                boolean dup = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MqttServiceConstants.DUPLICATE)));

                // build the result
                MqttMessageHack message = new MqttMessageHack(payload);
                message.setQos(qos);
                message.setRetained(retained);
                message.setDuplicate(dup);

                // move on
                hasNext = c.moveToNext();
                return new DbStoredData(messageId, clientHandle, topic, message);
            }
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Value must be ≥ 0 but 'getColumnIndex' can be -1
```

for each of the 'getColumnIndex above.

This is an error code since it is a red circle with an exclamation point in the middle displayed in the "Problems/Current File" window of my Android Studio project.

How do I rewrite them to get rid of the error messages?

Comment: What type is `c`? Is this a warning or an exception? What's the call stack? Did you make sure, that the columns you ask for actually exist? Looks like its 0-based. Did you try to debug the thing?

Comment: "I don't use a Cursor that I know of" but... it's right there, in the code, being used. What line is being pointed out?

Comment: It's just an analyzer warning and you can just ignore it. Right-clicking on the warning should bring up a menu with suppression options.